# SpriteRenderer batching issue, with Z-Position and Order in Layer

Tags: unity, sprites, batching

I have two sprites (they look the same but with different colors):

[image]

I want them to be positioned like on the image above, so there's a feel like blue is standing on the green one.
There are two ways to achieve that:

- Blue block with `Order in layer 1`, Green block with `Order in layer 0`
- Blue block with lower `Z coordinate`, so it's physically in front of the green one.

Both of the concepts appear to **break batching** between these two objects. They're on the same atlas (I've tested it by setting the same Z position and Sorting Order and batching works).

How can I achieve batching here?

Answer (score 1):

No, order (be it due to different Z position, different Order in layer, etc.) doesn't break sprite batching.

The most probable cause is that those sprites are using different `Materials`: you can't batch such sprites.

Comment: You can, however, achieve different colors with a single material by using a [`MaterialPropertyBlock`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialPropertyBlock.html)

Comment: @Draco18s Do you think that the `MaterialPropertyBlock` could be useful for sprites' colors? What I mean is that I understand the use of it for 3D, mesh rendered objects, but in the case of the `Sprite Renderer` component we already have the `Color` property.

Comment: `SpriteRenderer` inherits from `Renderer`, which is what supplies `SetPropertyBlock`, so I assume it works.

Comment: No, I don't mean that, functionally they both work the same, but when dealing with sprites I found that using the `Color` property is better since we can change/see it directly in the Inspector on a sprite-by-sprite basis without having to look at code.

Comment: Point. I don't know if that breaks batching or not though, the documentation doesn't say.